# How to split argument array with a comma?

Tags: node.js

This is for a Discord Bot based on NodeJS. Basically what I am trying to do is get the user arguments but I want the user inputted argument to be separated by a comma. So for example, if a user did this command `!check this is arg1, this is arg2`.

I have attempted the following:

`const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(',');`

But when I do that, it just doesn't do anything at all, like if I call the command it won't even do anything, but if I do:

`const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');`

The command responds as it should, but now it's splitting the arguments at a space instead of a comma.

This is my code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(',');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command == "check"){
        console.log(args);
        if(args == "") return message.channel.send("You didn't specify any symptoms.");

        let s1 = args[0];
        let s2 = args[1];
        if(typeof s2 != "undefined"){
            return message.channel.send(`Args: ${s1}, ${s2}`);    
        } else {
            return message.channel.send(`Args: ${s1}`);    
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: You said nothing about a semi-colon. Is this a typo: `.split(';')`

Comment: `split(', ').trim()` ?

Comment: Yes, my bad it is a typo. I was trying other keys. They all don't work except the (' ') space.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar, I tried using that and I get ".trim is not a function."

Comment: oh my bad; `split(', ').map(arg => arg.trim())` or if you're expecting more space you can use regex `split(/\s?,\s?/)` etc

Comment: It's not giving me an error anymore but it's going back to what it was doing before, it just won't do anything. I get no response?

Comment: `!check this is arg1, this is arg2` <- when input is this you want -> `['!check' 'this is arg1', 'this is arg2']` ??

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Yes, that is correct. Well, I won't get the "!check" because I sliced it but yes, that is what I want. I even put "console.log(args);" to check and see if it's working properly but it doesn't even log it.

Comment: Okay, scratch that. When entering the command "!check something like this, or this" the console responds with "['or this']", so it's only grabbing the second argument.

Comment: what is your `prefix` and is it guaranteed to slice of the preceding `!check` or other command?

Comment: The prefix is `!` and `check` is the command. Yeah, it does slice it.

Comment: _"!check something like this, or this" the console responds with "['or this']"_ - It is because of `split()` and `shift()`. See carefully, when you split it, it becomes: `['check something like this', 'or this']` and when you shift it then you get `['or this']`

Comment: @rv7 Thank you, now it works. Thank you naga as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general suggestion would be to do something like this:

```
// suppose
var message = "!check this is arg1, this is arg2"

// use regex to separate command (and grab it) from args
var input = message.match(/^!(\b\w+\b) (.*)/i)

// output: Array(3) [ "!check this is arg1, this is arg2", "check", "this is arg1, this is arg2" ]
// then input[1] is your command, input[2] are the args

// split without regex is usually faster
var args = input[1].split(', ').map(arg => arg.trim())
// output is Array [ "this is arg1", "this is arg2" ]
```

You can go [here](https://regex101.com/) to translate the `regex`

Answer (score 0):

### You Can Use `.split(',')`.

**EXAMPLE**

```js
const text = 'this is arg1, this is arg2' // text to split

const textarr = text.split(', ');
for(var i = 0; i < textarr.length; i++){
   console.log(textarr[i] + '\n')
}
```